# Customizing bootstrap grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

---

I need to design grid using bootstrap, like in the picture that I have uploaded.Please help me.

Comment: go to this site and easily design for pc,mobile etc   http://shoelace.io/

Answer (score 0):

I think something along the lines of

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="content-here">
       <img src="img1.jpg" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="boxes">
       Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
       Box 2
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
       Box 3
    </div>
    <div class="boxes">
       Box 4
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content-here { height: 400px; }
.boxes { float:left; width:50%; height:200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid system code might look like this :

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <img src="example.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="example.jpg">
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="example.jpg">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="example.jpg">
           </div>
           <div class="col-sm-12">
              <img src="example.jpg">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After that, you can specify the width and height of each image. If you want your image to take a full width (means taking all space of the column), you can set `width:100%`.